# CT Segmentation Model Intersection

Tags: 3d-models

I am using (micro)CT data and generating 3-D models using CTAn - a SkyScan piece of software: [Bruker - Control and reconstruction programs](http://bruker-microct.com/products/downloads.htm).

Basically I am using simple thresholding to create 3-D model STL files.

What I would like to do is get the number of voxels where the surface area of the two models touch.

Imagine having a model that is a sphere with another model within it that is exposed on a portion of the sphere.  I want to know the surface area of that exposed portion.

Does anybody have any advice?  I have been banging my head against tools like 3D-Slicer, Seg3D, ITK-Snap and so on and have not been able to find this capability.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes the following

a-The scaling factor for the object is correct i.e real world dimensions .

b- There is a .STL file available .

c- **This will take some 3ds max skill and time .**

***Steps to be followed -***

1- Take the .stl file into Autodesk 3ds max .

2- Now we are going to trace the exposed surface using a process called ***reptology*** . Here is link to get you started - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azkbuZloTqo .

3- Once you are satisfied with recreating the mesh and sure it is as accurate as humanly possible , run the measure utility on the recreated part .

This is the link . https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-12CDEA7A-042E-4CB3-9BF6-8191D3290CD8-htm.html .

If there is a upper side and a lower side to the model then you should divide the surface area in half ( in this case it would be ).

3Ds max is very accurate if your part is designed properly .

4- This can be done directly on the .STL file if you can efficiently isolate your target area , lemme warn you this is not an easy task .STL files are notoriously difficult to edit. ( its much easier to redesign on top  )

Try it should work out fine .

Please do not waste time processing .STL files on 3D-Slicer, Seg3D, ITK-Snap
they are mostly for file preparation i.e (.STL file generation ),viewing and study purposes only .